Access to Venmo/Zelle/Cashapp as a visitor to the US
Venmo, Zelle, Cash App etc seems to be increasingly taking over from cash for payments in the US, particularly person-to-person transfers like splitting restaurant bills, tips, etc.  However, these all seems to assume/require that its users have a US bank account.
Is there any way for a temporary visitor to the US to sign up?  Preferably without opening a bank account, but if one is required, is there a straightforward, ideally all-online way to open one without incurring ongoing fees?  This Q&A on Money.SE suggests it's possible, at least by visiting a branch in person, but is short on specifics.

Wise suggests that it is possible to use something called Plaid to link a Venmo account to a Wise account's US details, but I have not tried it myself, and the numerous parties involved may cause the fees to start to add up if you're not careful.

Just hand the person cash. Generally, the issue is people not carrying cash to pay, particularly small bills and coins that don't come out of an ATM. It's not that the recipient refuses to accept cash. (And even if they don't like taking cash, they should tolerate it coming from a foreign visitor) Or if you're in a restaurant, use your cash to cover the tip, put any extra in the bill pile. The waiter just punches in the cash and the POS system will put the rest on the card.

What ever happened to Paypal?  Wasn't that originally founded exactly for this purpose, and it works with accounts from many countries?

@gerrit amusingly, paypal owns venmo, but you cannot send money from a paypal account to a venmo one.

@ave What I don't understand is what problem Venmo/Zello/Cashapp/Swish/Vipps/others solve that Paypal doesn't, except that it adds restrictions that Paypal didn't have.  Not that I like Paypal, but at least it doesn't have national restrictions.

@gerrit "Social" Everybody can see transaction values and a cute emoji-laden memo line on the new apps. Presumably it's to establish trust that it's the right account, but it really is a form of conspicuous consumption.

@gerrit Here is a national restriction with PayPal: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51005/18147

@FranckDernoncourt The restriction "I have to make a new account when I have a new country" is a lot less severe than "impossible to use for foreigners".

@gerrit Well since when did we stop making apps/services/companies just because there's one that already does X thing?

@AzorAhai-him- We don't, but to succeed in a competitive market you typically need to offer something that's in some way better than what exists, in particular in markets with a high cost of entry, which would include peer-to-peer payment services.


Preferably without opening a bank account

https://wise.com/us/blog/add-money-venmo-without-bank-account and https://help.venmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/235224088-Bank-Accounts-Cards-FAQ: one can use some prepaid cards to add money into Venmo (some people on Reddit confirm that for some prepaid cards).

if one [US bank account] is required, is there a straightforward, ideally all-online way to open one without incurring ongoing fees

Non-US residents can create Schwab One International® accounts: https://international.schwab.com/ (application form).
Some non-US residents can also create an HSBC account in the US.
Bank of America doesn't allow non-US residents to create bank accounts anymore (stopped around 2018 or 2019).

It's not clear to me if the Schwab account can be used with Venmo and the like, as the question asks, or only for making investments. Regardless, even if it would technically work, the application form suggests a minimum US$25,000 balance, which is probably not suitable for most short-term visitors who just want to transfer a few dollars to their friends.

Adding a credit card to Venmo seems like an interesting option, but the site says you have to have a US phone number to sign up: https://help.venmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/209690188-Requirements

@lambshaanxy prepaid US SIM card?

It's not a blocker, just another hoop to jump through.

@lambshaanxy btw I wonder whether Venmo accepts non-US cards.

The Wise page is not clear, but couldn’t one just use the US account details they provide?

@jcaron I'd guess so but I haven't tried
